# Using method from class in another .h file in c++

Tags: c++, class

I'm new in C++, and have been given a (relatively) complex piece of code.

I want to call a function `transmit()` from a .h file in another .c file. 
The `transmit()` is in the file serviceUart.hpp which content looks like this:

**serviceUart.hpp**

```
class ServiceUart
{
public:
    ServiceUart();
  void ioConfig(); // sets io HW ports and pins. Only needed at first boot
    void ioInit(); //
    bool readTrigger();
    bool detectConnection() {return (m_rxPin.get()|| m_enabled);}
    bool startup();
    bool transmit(const char* s, uint16_t length, bool wait = false);
```

The file drvr.cpp is where I try calling the function. A snippet of what I think is relevant from that file looks like this:

**drvr.cpp**

```
#include "EHS5_drv.hpp"

char debug[] = "I got to here!";
transmit(debug,true);
```

I tried serviceUart.transmit and serviceUart::transmit, but no matter what I try, I get the error code `#20 identifier "transmit" is undefined". I guess I'm misunderstanding the syntax?

Comment: You need an object to call `transmit()`

Comment: To call a method you need an object of the class `ServiceUart`, I would suggest a good C++ book if this is a new concept to you.

Comment: Do you *have* a `ServiceUart` object instantiated? And note that you pass `true` for the *`length`* argument (and since you don't have such an overload, this is my guess as to the problem). Please edit your question to include the *full* and *complete* build output, copy-pasted as text.

Comment: I recognize by these comments, that I need to study more before posting. I will take @drescherjm 's proposal to heart. 
Im also new on SO. Should I delete the question, or can someone "shut it down" for me? Thanks for the comments.

Comment: Easier if you delete it.

Comment: Are you from Java background?

Comment: @MartinRasmussen No need to do anything - you asked a question, you got your answer. This is how it's supposed to work. You might want to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer which you like the most in order to mark your question answered.

Comment: To answer @Hemil I'm not from any specific background. I'm an electronics engineer student, now in an internship, where I've been given a C++ code, I had to tune for another module.

Comment: @anatolyg thanks for the guidance, I will mark the answer.

Comment: I asked because if you Java but not C++, there is a hell lot of difference in the way the Java and C++ manage pointers (which the accepted answer used). You can easily get confused

Comment: And you probably want to use const std::string and not const char*

Comment: We had a turbo-curse on objective oriented programming, but most of the stuff went over my head at that time. I picket up a nice book on the subject, and my mistakes are much clearer now ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method `bool transmit(const char* s, uint16_t length, bool wait = false);` is defined in `ServiceUart`. You have to create an object of `ServiceUart` class and then call method `transmit()`

```
char debug[] = "I got to here!";

ServiceUart obj;
obj.transmit(debug,true);
```

Or with `new`

```
ServiceUart* obj = new ServiceUart();
obj->transmit(debug,true);
delete obj;
```

Don't forget to delete obj.

Comment: You might want to put the normal object first and then the new example. Because the person is new, and God forbid if he comes from Java, Java and C++ behave are different in a hell lot of ways

Answer (score 2):

You probably want:

```
char[] debug = "I got here";

ServiceUart serviceObg;
obj.transmit(debug, true);
```